# Making references to another class with multiple declarations

Tags: c++

I am creating an audio application that has 4 looper tracks and a transport bar with a play button. I'm trying to get the play button to play all 4 loopers at the same time when clicked.

In my TranportBarGui class, in the .h file, I have made a reference to the Looper instance as you can see:

```
class TransportBarGui : public Component,
                    public Button::Listener,
                    public Timer

{
public:

    TransportBarGui(Looper& looperRef_);

    ~TransportBarGui();
private:
    TextButton playButton;
    Looper& looperRef; //reference to looper
```

and in the TransportBarGui.cpp file, when the button gets pressed, the looper is played using the looper reference:

```
void TransportBarGui::buttonClicked (Button* button)
{
    if (button == &playButton)
    {
        if (looperRef.getPlayState() == 0)
        {

            looperRef.setPlayState(!looperRef.getPlayState()); //turn on looper
            playButton.setButtonText("Stop");
            playButton.setToggleState(looperRef.getPlayState(), dontSendNotification);
            DBG(looperRef.getPlayState());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is i have declared 4 Loopers all together in the audio class (this is the class that does the audio processing) in the audio.h file ass you can see here:

```
private:
    AudioDeviceManager audioDeviceManager;
    Looper looper;
    Looper looper2;
    Looper looper3;
    Looper looper4;
```

and when i press the play button on the transport bar, it only plays back the first looper.

Is there a way I can get it to play all the loopers rather than just the first?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the `looperRef` is. That is a reference to one specific Looper instance, not to the Looper class. I think that what you'd need to do is (in the buttonClicked function) simply call the same function you call for `looperRef` on the other three objects as well.

Comment: Okay thanks for that I have updated the question. And how do I go about calling the same function on the other three objects? That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: `looper.func(); looper2.func();` etc... Or better, put them in a vector and use a loop.

Comment: @interjay what do you mean by "looper.func(); looper2.func(); etc"? What would the functions be and in what files?

Comment: One way is to put that in a function in the class containing the four objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the `TransportBarGui` know about the existence of *all* of the loopers.  The minimal change would look something like:

```
class TransportBarGui : public Component,
                    public Button::Listener,
                    public Timer
{
public:

    TransportBarGui(Looper& l1_, Looper& l2_, Looper& l3_, Looper& l4_);

    ~TransportBarGui();
private:
    TextButton playButton;
    Looper& looperRef1; //reference to looper
    Looper& looperRef2;
    Looper& looperRef3;
    Looper& looperRef4;
```

You then repeat your existing logic for all four loopers.  But that's a bit yucky - there's an awful lot of repetition.  (Particularly if you want to add a fifth looper at some point.)

I'd switch to a vector of pointers to loopers:

```
class TransportBarGui : public Component,
                    public Button::Listener,
                    public Timer
{
public:

    TransportBarGui(const std::vector<Looper*>& loopers_);

    ~TransportBarGui();
private:
    TextButton playButton;
    const std::vector<Looper*>& loopers; // The loopers we care about.
```

and then the play button looks like:

```
void TransportBarGui::buttonClicked (Button* button)
{
    if (button == &playButton)
    {
        for (const auto pLooper : loopers)
        {
            auto& looperRef = *pLooper;
            if (looperRef.getPlayState() == 0)
            {
                looperRef.setPlayState(1); //turn on looper
                DBG(looperRef.getPlayState());
                playButton.setToggleState(looperRef.getPlayState(), dontSendNotification);
        }
        playButton.setButtonText("Stop");
    }
}
```

That's a bit tacky, as it sets the playButton toggle state four times - but you want to think about how you handle the case where some of the loopers start, and some don't.

Comment: For now I have used your first solution until I learn more myself about vectors, however I still can't get it to work. It still only plays back the first looper, its as if each looperRef is referencing the 'Looper looper' and not 'Looper looper1' etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of the TransportBarGui constructor, and the call to it please?  It will need to look something like:  `TransportBarGui::TransportBarGui(Looper& l1_, Looper& l2_, Looper& l3_, Looper& l4_) : looperRef1(l1_), looperRef2(l2_), looperRef3(l3_), looperRef4(l4_)` and `TransportBarGui bar(looper1, looper2, looper3, looper4);`

Comment: In particular, beware copy/paste errors where the construction looks like `bar(looper1, looper1, looper1, looper1)` or similar.

Comment: That's what mine looks like, except the call to it looks like this: 'TransportBarGui(Looper& looperRef1_, Looper& looperRef2_, Looper& looperRef3_, Looper& looperRef4_);'

Comment: That's not a call.  That's the declaration of the constructor (and I approve of the longer names -it was just making the line too long, and this is suposed to be tutorial code).

Comment: Yep, my mistake, so thats the declaration, and the call to it looks exactly like what you wrote in the comments except with the longer names.

Comment: What framework are you using?  Does it support multiple loopers playing at once?

Comment: I am using Juce and made the loopers myself, and yes, because if i just press the play button on each looper myself they play at the same time.

Comment: I think you need to post another question with your new code.

Comment: I made a copy and past error in void "TransportBarGui::buttonClicked (Button* button)", your solution was correct all along. Thanks!